# Проблема с вызовом WinAPI функции в C#

Tags: c#, winapi

Доброго времени суток всем, товарищи!

Как часть функционала моего приложения является смена обоев рабочего стола. С помощью гугла я нашел популярное решение на языке программирования C#.

Полный код класса прикрепляю ниже.

```
namespace BingPhotoOfTheDay.etc
{
    static class bing
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern Int32 SystemParametersInfo(
        UInt32 action, UInt32 uParam, String vParam, UInt32 winIni);

        private static readonly UInt32 SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x14;
        private static readonly UInt32 SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
        private static readonly UInt32 SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02;

        public static string GetURLToImage()
        {

            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadFile("http://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=xml&idx=0&n=1&mkt=en-US", "parse.xml");

            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load("parse.xml");
            XmlElement xRoot = xDoc.DocumentElement;

            string URL = "";
            XmlNode node = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/images/image/urlBase");

            URL = node.InnerText + "_1920x1080.jpg";

            return URL;
        }



        public static void DownloadImage()
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadFile("https://bing.com" + GetURLToImage(), "image.jpg");

            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile("image.jpg");
            bitmap.Save("image.bmp");

        }

        public static void SetWallpaper()
        {
            SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, "image.bmp",
            SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Однако, наблюдаю проблему с вызовом данной функции. Программа работает без ошибок, однако вместо ожидаемого результата смены обоев рабочего стола получаю черные обои рабочего стола.

К сожалению не знаю в какую сторону копать.
Прошу помощи

Comment: Проблемы с SystemParametersInfo? Кучу ненужного кода можно удалить и сделать минимальный воспроизводимый пример. В процессе рекомендую добавить проверку возвращаемого из API значения и получения кода ошибки. Код ошибки сильно помог бы понять в чем же у вас там проблема.

Comment: Кода ошибки среда не выдает, программа не вызывает исключительные ситуации. Просто вместо текущего изображение рабочего стола становится черный фон. А есть вероятность того, что в  Windows 10 что-то изменили в API?

Comment: MSDN вот, например, говорит: "If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError."

Comment: Признаюсь, с WinAPI работаю в первый раз и не знаю как сделать то что вы просите. Можете помочь с этим?

Comment: Вы не знаете как проверить возвращаемое из функции значение? Боюсь, это будет слишком сложно объяснить.

Comment: ты проверял картинку куда сохранял? есть такой файл? он нормально показывается?

Comment: Почти на 100% уверен, что _SystemParametersInfo_ пытается загрузить картинку не оттуда куда ты ее сохранил, и поэтому просто показывает черный экран. Попробуй прописать полный путь к картинке

Comment: Картинка сохраняется ,открывается, все с ней хорошо. Через Process.Start так же стартует. Функция SetWallpaper не вызывает ошибок

Comment: _Попробуй прописать полный путь к картинке_

Comment: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+@"\image.bmp"

Comment: Действительно помогло, благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае передается путь относительно папки, в которой запущено приложение.

Но, так как неизвестно относительно чего берется путь в самой функции *SystemParametersInfo*, по указанному пути ничего не находится, и вместо обоев выставляется черный фоновый цвет.

Для решения проблемы нужно передавать *полный* путь к картинке.